# Can I make a WEP wifi and crack it using two virtual machines?

Tags: wifi, wep

I am using VirtualBox, Kali linux as the attacker vm and xubuntu as the supposed AP. However, I only have my wireless pcie card on my actual pc and it seems that making a virtual interface card doesn't work unless I am doing it wrong.

Is there any workaround or a way to use my actual wifi card? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Don't you have a real hardware router/AP laying around as well?

Comment: Yes correct, I do have a real one, this is the household router. How can I use that?

Comment: set it up to use WEP as you want to...

Comment: Unfortunately I only see WPA2 and WPA-Auto as options, there is no WEP.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to access the computers builtin wireless card in virtualbox. Also, most builtin wireless cards do not support monitor mode, which is often required for wireless attacks.

One solution might be to get 2 usb wireless adapters and use the USB pass through option in virtualbox to give both virtual machines a wireless card.

https://adamtheautomator.com/vbox-usb-passthrough/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Correct, I have tried that but unfortunately I am now running into driver issues with Linux and despite the help I got, it just doesn't seem to work out for me. I am thinking of abandoning the idea and think of something else.